# LSTM num_units size, ie size of hidden_layer

Tags: python, keras, lstm

I often see `natural language processing` tasks use `LSTM` in a way that they first use a `embedding layer` followed by an `LSTM layer` of the size of the embedding, i.e. if a word is represented by a 1x300 vector `LSTM(300)` is used.

E.g.:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(vocabulary, hidden_size, input_length=num_steps))
model.add(LSTM(hidden_size, return_sequences=True))
```

Is there a particular reason for doing so? Like a better representation of the meaning?

Comment: Interesting question.... techinally, we can choose any number, but if that equality can bring better learning is something open for research....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's any special reason/need for this and frankly I haven't seen that many cases myself where this is the case (i.e. using the `LSTM` hidden units == `Embedding` size). The only effect this has is there's a single memory cell for each embedding vector element (which I don't think is a requirement or a necessity).

Having said that, I thought I might mention something extra. That is, there's a reason for having an `Embedding` layer in this setup. In fact a very good reason(s). Let's consider the two options,

1. Using one hot encoding for word representation
2. Using `Embeddings` for word represetnations

Option 2 has several advantages over option 1.

- The dimensionality of the inputs is way smaller when you use an embedding layer (e.g. 300 as opposed to 50000)
- You're providing the **flexibility** to the model to learn a word representation that is infact suited to the task your solving. In other words, you are not restricting the representation of words to remain constant during the training process.
- If you use a pretrained word embedding layer to initialize the `Embedding` layer, even better. You are bringing word semantics in to the task you are solving. That always help to solve the task better. This is analogous to asking a toddler that doesn't understand the meaning of words to do something text-related (e.g. order words in the correct grammatical order) vs asking a 3-year old to do the same task. They both might eventually do it. But one will do it quicker and better.